# Javascript alert on dropdown menus?

Tags: javascript, forms, drop-down-menu, alert

I have a javascript alert on my form here - http://investing.uglyopportunities.com/opportunity/ I have the javascript function working correctly for my form.  Except I also want the javascript to alert when the user doesn't select from either of the two drop down menus.  I really don't have much experience at all with javascript, so keep that in mind!  Here is my current code. I really appreciate any help

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
function validateForm() {
    var a = document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_FirstName"].value;
    var b = document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_Email"].value;
    var c = document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_Phone1"].value;
    var e = document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_City"].value;
    var f = document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_State"].value;
    var g = document.forms["myform"]["inf_field_PostalCode"].value;

    if (a == null || a == "" || a == "First Name Here") {
        alert("Please enter your First Name!");
        return false;
    }
    if (c == null || c == '' || c == "Enter Your Phone Here" || c.length < 9) {
        alert("Please insert your phone number!");
        return false;
    }
if (e == null || e == '' ||e == "City") {
        alert("Please insert your city");
        return false;
    }

    if (f == null || f == '' || f == "State") {
        alert("Please insert your state ");
        return false;
    }

if (g == null || g == '' ||g == "Postal Code" || c.length < 5) {
        alert("Please insert your postal code");
        return false;
    }



    var emailRegEx = /^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i;
    if (document.myform.inf_field_Email.value.search(emailRegEx) == -1) {
        alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
        return false;
    }
}
// ]]>
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.getElementById('inf_custom_LevelofInterest').value == '' || document.getElementById('inf_custom_Doyouhavemoneytoinvest').value == ''){
alert('please select ...');
return false;
}
```